# SQLite storing Date issues

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to store a user inputted date on SQLite, however all I have managed to figure out is how to add the current date as set by the android device. I want the user to be able a date for expirydate and recieveddate, as opposed to them being taken from the device settings.

Here is my code..

```
package com.example.bash1.sqlitediss;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
// Database name
public static final String DATABASE_STOCKDB = "Stock.db";
// Column names
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "stock_table";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "Name";
public static final String COL_3 = "Datereceived";
public static final String COL_4 = "Expirydate";


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_STOCKDB, null, 1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COL_1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COL_2 + " TEXT," + COL_3 + " DATE," + COL_4 + " DATE" + ")");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData(String Name, String Datereceived, String Expirydate){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2, Name);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    contentValues.put(COL_3, dateFormat.format(new Date()));
//    contentValues.put(COL_3, Datereceived);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    if (result == -1 )
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}

// Calls all data for the View Database Button
public Cursor getAllData (){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    return res;

}

}
```

Comment: I believe you need to store date in this format `9999-12-31 23:59:59` and visit https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use ORDER BY to sort either by ascending or descending, below is the query

This is for ascending for descending change the ASC to DESC alone and put your appropriate table name and column name. **DATE_ADD** function can be used to do this.

**NOTE:** Current date should be in sql date format.

```
"select * from " + TABLE_NAME + "column_name < (DATE_SUB(yourCurrentDate, INTERVAL 30 DAY));"
```

Comment: Would it be possible to make a query that only reported on items that have Less than 30 days before their expiry date? The expiry date is formated as yy:mm:dd

Comment: `ASC` is optional, since it's the default, if omitted.

Comment: @AshleyThompson:: This can be achieved through this query.

Comment: It needs to be something like to print the Name, which is COL_1 + (COL_4(expirydate) if <30 days)

Comment: So something like
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE (julianday(expirydate)-julianday(SYNTAX FOR CURRENT DATE ON DEVICE)) <= 30  ;

Answer (score 0):

Well below is just snap with query and how to store date in table (ie. date-format).. Hope this helps.
[image]

**UPDATED:**
Query to get *currentDay-30days* will look like this

```
Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -30);
String last30Days=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(calendar.getTime());
System.out.println(last30Days);

//your query look like this
//"SELECT * FROM your_table where date_column_name>'"+last30Days+"'"
//SELECT * FROM your_table where date_column_name>'2016-03-20 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Thats great thanks, but how would i get it to run the query from 30 days from todays date? instead of specifying a date?

Comment: I dont know any kind of method is there or not.. but usually I do this with java `Calender` api  ->  currentDate - 30days..

Comment: Im sorry i completed said the wrong thing. I need a query from a selected date, so Selected date - 30 days.. SOrry!!

Comment: and what is the date format to the selected date.. or add the date selection code to your post.